# How can I inject multiple repositories in a NServicebus message handler?

Tags: nhibernate, structuremap, nservicebus

I use the following:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
   void Add(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T>
{
  private readonly ISession session;

  public Repository(ISession session)
  {
    this.session = session;
  }

  public void Add(T entity)
  {
     session.Save(entity);
  }
}

public class SomeHandler : IHandleMessages<SomeMessage>
{
  private readonly IRepository<EntityA> aRepository;
  private readonly IRepository<EntityB> bRepository;

  public SomeHandler(IRepository<EntityA> aRepository, IRepository<EntityB> bRepository)
  {
    this.aRepository = aRepository;
    this.bRepository = bRepository; 
  }

  public void Handle(SomeMessage message)
  {
   aRepository.Add(new A(message.Property);
   bRepository.Add(new B(message.Property);
  }
}

public class MessageEndPoint : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
   public void Init()
   {
      ObjectFactory.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.For<ISession>()
                .CacheBy(InstanceScope.ThreadLocal)
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
            config.ForRequestedType(typeof(IRepository<>))
                .TheDefaultIsConcreteType(typeof(Repository<>));
   }
}
```

My problem with the threadlocal storage is, is that the same session is used during the whole application thread. I discovered this when I saw the first level cache wasn't cleared. What I want is using a new session instance, before each call to IHandleMessages<>.Handle.
How can I do this with structuremap? Do I have to create a message module?

Comment: Are you using a messagemodule to handle the opening of the session?

Comment: Currently not, I just use structuremap to resolve the session. Do I have to?

Comment: You're right in that the same session is used for all requests to the same thread. This is because NSB doesn't create new threads for each request. I don't have a workaround right now, needs to think through this one a bit more.

Comment: Working around the fact that NSB reused thread will be hard. To have the cache cleared you can implement a message module that clears the session...

 public class SessionClearModule:IMessageModule
    {
        private IContainer container;

        public SessionClearModule(IContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public void HandleBeginMessage()
        {
            container.GetInstance<ISession>().Clear();
        }

        public void HandleEndMessage()
        {
        }

        public void HandleError()
        {
        }
    }

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm afraid that the session can keep a connection open. It doesn't matter if it's once, but I want to be able to use the message handler in multiple threads on multiple machines talking to one database, so I'm looking for a solution that really creates a new session every time.

Comment: I think this can be acheived by implementing a custom cache mode for StructureMap that exposes the cache and thereby allows us to clear it using a message module. I'll get back to you about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in that the same session is used for all requests to the same thread. This is because NSB doesn't create new threads for each request. The workaround is to add a custom cache mode and have it cleared when message handling is complete.

1.Extend the thread storage lifecycle and hook it up a a message module

```
public class NServiceBusThreadLocalStorageLifestyle : ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle, IMessageModule
{

    public void HandleBeginMessage(){}

    public void HandleEndMessage()
    {
        EjectAll();
    }

    public void HandleError(){}
}
```

2.Configure your structuremap as follows:

```
For<<ISession>>
.LifecycleIs(new NServiceBusThreadLocalStorageLifestyle())
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice to hear! I'm going to include the custom lifecycle in our StructureMap object builder as soon as I can.

Comment: The trunk version of the StructureMap builder now includes the above lifecycle